# Solarium vs CiviCRM

Tags: drupal, security

Drupal solr integration, as of Drupal 8.7.8 solr integration, as of  8.x-3.7 requires solarium/solarium:^5.1 which requires symfony/event-dispatcher:^4.3 which breaks civicrm.

To maintain module security, we're forced to upgrade soon.

Are there any workarounds or patches planned for this?

Comment: Have you already looked at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/issues/92 ?

Comment: @Demerit That comment deserves to be an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

There is some information at this lab ticket about the current status:
https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/issues/92

You can join the conversation there.